# Is the function "signInWithPopup" from firebase supported on Expo?

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory, expo

I am trying to implement an authentication login method through Azure AD with Firebase on my Expo app.

Here is an extraction of my code, which looks exactly like the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth#web-version-9_3):

```
  const signInWithMicrosoft = () => {
    const auth = initializeAuth(firebaseApp);
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {

      const credential = OAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
      const accessToken = credential.accessToken;
      const idToken = credential.idToken;
      navigation.navigate("Home")
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle error.
    });
  }
```

When pressing the button to activate the function, the following error message shows up:

> TypeError: (0, _auth.signInWithPopup) is not a function. (In '(0, _auth.signInWithPopup)(auth, provider)', '(0, _auth.signInWithPopup)' is undefined)

I tried importing the functions as:

```
import { signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth"
```

and

```
import { signInWithPopup } from "firebase/compat/auth"
```

And neither of them seem to work.

Is there any way I can get this function to work, or the solution would be going another way around? I don't know if functions such as SignInWithPopup and SignInWithRedirect are supported in Expo, since it is a Mobile application.

If you have any tip, clue or information on **using firebase auth methods in a Expo app**, please share below and I will be very happy to read it and comment on.